# invalid input syntax for integer: "\N" when gpload a text file

Tags: copy, greenplum

I found one strange problem. With greenplum gpload tool, I tried to import data from a single text file to greenplum db.
The content of file t1.out is:

```
\N|24234243
\N|\N
12342|\N
```

and gpload version is:

`gpload version 5.3.0 build
 commit:2155c5a8cf8bb7f13f49c6e248fd967a74fed591`

and the table t1 is as follow:

```
test=# \d t1;
  Table "public.t1"
  Column |  Type  | Modifiers 
  --------+--------+-----------
   id1    | bigint | 
   id2    | bigint |
```

when I use gpload with t1.yaml, I got following error:

```
2019-04-09 20:12:18|WARN|Please use following query to access the detailed error
2019-04-09 20:12:18|WARN|select * from   p_read_error_log('ext_gpload_reusable_b7ef1344_5ac0_11e9_b6fc_fa163e2d09a1') where cmdtime > to_timestamp('1554811937.76')
```

and when I ran this sql(made small change only selecting two key fields) in postgresql, I got following errors:

```
    errmsg                       |   rawdata 

invalid input syntax for integer: "\N", column id1 | \N|24234243
invalid input syntax for integer: "\N", column id1 | \N|\N
invalid input syntax for integer: "\N", column id2 | 12342|\N
```

It showed all the 3 lines were not imported with 'invalid input syntax for integer: "\N"'.

but I can use COPY command to import above 3 items into t1 successfully.

I tried several ways to find why, but failed. Part of my t1.yaml as follows:

```
    - FORMAT: text 
    - DELIMITER: '|' 
    - ESCAPE: 'OFF' 
    - NULL_AS: '\N' 
    - ERROR_LIMIT: 100
```

BTW:https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/530/utility_guide/admin_utilities/gpload.html#topic1__cfnullas has shown that the default NULL_AS is \N, and gpload has found \N, and why it failed to mark the two field as NULL? 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What version of GPDB are you using?
There was a known issue in v5 that was fixed in 5.6+

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/560/relnotes/GPDB_561_README.html

> 29197 - gpload/ gpfdist
>
> When running a gpload operation, the gpfdist utility did not recognize a \N as the NULL character when the gpload configuration file specified a null character null_as: '\N'. When processing the configuration file, the gpload utility incorrectly escaped the backslash () with another backslash.
> This issue has been resolved. The gpload utility has been improved to properly handle a backslash when processing the null_as property.

Comment: I use GPDB 5.3. so I had to upgrade GPDB to 5.6+? Is it possible to give a patch for 5.3?

Comment: Thanks a lot for Stephens, I will try the latest version.